# User input expected float but turned into string Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code:

```
def giftcard():
    while True:
        card = input("Do you have a gift card (Y or N)? ")
        if card in ["Y", "y", "yes", "Yes"]:
            while True:
                try:
                    amt = float(input("How much money would you like to apply from card? "))
                    if amt > price:
                        print("Amount can't be greater than bill amount. Try again.")
                        continue
                    elif amt < price:
                        break
                except:
                    print("Invalid. Try again.")
                    continue
        elif card in ["N", "n", "no", "No"]:
            amt = 0
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid. Try again.")
            continue
        break
    return amt, card


price = 8.70
card, amt = giftcard()
print(amt)
```

The output:
{
Do you have a gift card (Y or N)? y
How much money would you like to apply from card? 5
y
}
As you can see its printing "y" rather than "5" which is very odd. I set amt as a float for a user to input and when I print (amt) it suddenly prints the input for (card). What have I done wrong I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: you use `return amt, card` and `card, amt = giftcard()` so you have variables in wrong order and you get `amt = card` and `card = amt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You returns

```
return amt, card
```

and as you see `amt` is first, and `card` is second

but you assing in different order

```
card, amt = giftcard()
```

so you assign value from `amt` to `card` and `card` to `amd`

You need in this order

```
amt, card = giftcard()
```

---

It doesn't matter how you name variables inside function and outside function - they can be different. It is important to return and assign values in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

You have your returns reversed. It should return card and then amt, not amt and then card.

Why? because your calling the function in this order:

```
card, amt = giftcard()
```

So the return values are not in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is this: `card, amt = giftcard()`. This means card = amt, and so it will print amt. Or it seems.

Also, to change to a float use the `float()` function. This changes string to float, like 5 to 5.00.

Answer (score 0):

The tuple you are returning if flipped.
In the function you create the tuple (amt, card)
but you store it into the tuple (card, amt)
Simply change the order of variable names in either place to fix it

```
return amt, card
card, amt = giftcard() # Error
```